# PostgreSQL ALTER VIEW Rewrite Changes AND / OR Meaning

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

We have a big view in PostgreSQL that is supposed to include this join (names changed to protect the innocent):

```
LEFT JOIN table1 ON
table4.a = table1.a AND
(regexp_split_to_array(table2.code::text, '_'::text))[1:2] = (regexp_split_to_array(table1.code::text, '_'::text))[1:2] AND
(
    table3.b = table1.b OR
    (table3.b IS NULL AND table1.b IS NULL) OR 
    (table3.b = 1 AND table1.b IS NULL) OR
    (table3.b IS NULL AND table1.b = 1)
) AND
(
    table3.c = table1.c OR 
    (table3.c IS NULL AND table1.c IS NULL) OR
    (table3.c = 1 AND table1.c IS NULL) OR
    (table3.c IS NULL AND table1.c = 1)
)
```

However, when we save the view definition using CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ... AS, it rewrites it and removes a bunch of the parenthesis, which substantially changes the meaning of the ANDs / ORs:

```
LEFT JOIN table1 ON
table4.a = table1.a AND
(regexp_split_to_array(table2.code::text, '_'::text))[1:2] = (regexp_split_to_array(table1.code::text, '_'::text))[1:2] AND
(
    table3.b = table1.b OR
    table3.b IS NULL AND
    table1.b IS NULL OR 
    table3.b = 1 AND
    table1.b IS NULL OR
    table3.b IS NULL AND
    table1.b = 1
) AND
(
    table3.c = table1.c OR 
    table3.c IS NULL AND
    table1.c IS NULL OR
    table3.c = 1 AND
    table1.c IS NULL OR
    table3.c IS NULL AND
    table1.c = 1
)
```

Those queries don't yield the same results.

(The data is from a 3rd party where tables get joined based on the numbers in a, b, and c, but if the ID is a 1 sometimes it's NULL, so 1 should match on NULL and vice-versa; it's messed up, but we don't want to change the data)

So in essence the rewrite is changing the meaning of the view and effectively breaking it.

Due to legacy software conflicts we're stuck on 9.4.26, so I'm not sure if the problem still exists.

Is there any way to prevent PostgreSQL from breaking the view during the rewrite (which I think is unavoidable)?

Thanks

Comment: "*removes a bunch of the parenthesis, which substantially changes the meaning of the ANDs / ORs*" - no, it doesn't. AND binds stronger than OR, these queries are still semantically equivalent (even if the second might be less readable). "*Those queries don't yield the same results.*" - are you sure there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about messing with how Postgres handles the view, but the path of least resistance may be rewriting your query to just use `AND`s and so avoid any sort of parentheses shenanigans. Something like:

```
LEFT JOIN table1 ON
table4.a = table1.a
AND (regexp_split_to_array(table2.code::text, '_'::text))[1:2] = (regexp_split_to_array(table1.code::text, '_'::text))[1:2]
 AND   coalesce(table3.b, 1) = coalesce(table1.b, 1)
 AND   coalesce(table3.c, 1) = coalesce(table1.c, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't store the view definition as a string, but it parses it into a "node tree" and stores it that way. This has the advantages that the view doesn't have to parsed each time, that it is immune to renaming of the underlying objects and that dependencies on those objects can be tracked.

Your parentheses may make the statement more readable, but they are syntactically irrelevant, so when PostgreSQL deparses the node tree into an SQL expression, it omits them.